# Echo effect during phone call

Tags: microphone, gsm, cellphone, telephone

What causes echo effect in telephone lines during phone calls? Does it mean that someone is spying on telephone line or? When I talk with some people, it happens, and with some of them not.

Comment: Spying shouldn't cause an echo, otherwise it would be too easy to tell.

Comment: These guys are using a crappy hands-free devices. So the mic is hearing the speaker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking to someone using speaker phone then yes it is likely acoustic echo where their mic is picking up their voice echoed back from the room/ car or whatever.

There is also hybrid echo which is where the 2 to 4 wire conversion at the central office does not impedance match perfectly so you get some reflected echo.

It can be worse if there is already a lot of delay on the line such as in a VoIP system.

Here's a link that talks about the [concepts](http://www.adaptivedigital.com/product/echo_cancel/echo_explain.htm).